# Inference in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I have stumbled upon the following reasoning, but I'm not sure if it's correct. Here it goes:
Domain X

1. $\forall x :\phi(x)⟹\gamma(x)$
2. Let $E\subseteq X⟹[\forall x\in E :\phi(x)⟹\gamma(x)]$
3. Suppose I know, by some property of $E$, that $\forall x\in E :\phi(x)$, that is for every $x\in E$, $\phi(x)$ is true.
4. [$\forall x\in E :\phi(x)] ⟹ \phi(x)$ (by universal instantation)
5. ⟹ $\gamma(x)$ (by universal instantation of 2. and by 4.)
6. ⟹ $\forall x\in E :\gamma(x)$ (by universal generalization)
7. Therefore: [$\forall x\in E :\phi(x)⟹\gamma(x)]\wedge [\forall x\in E :\phi(x)] ⟹ \forall x\in E :\gamma(x)$

It's like I have distributed the quantifier over the implication. Is this correct?

Comment: what do you mean 'It's like I have distributed the quantifier over the implication.' - is this refering to statement 7?

Comment: Yes, to statement 7 in particular.

Comment: your leap is $5\to6$, where you assume $\gamma(x)\implies\forall x\in E:\gamma(x)$ which is true in this case...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. $\forall x : \phi(x) \implies \gamma(x)$ (premise)
2. $E\subset X$ (premise)
3. $\forall x \in E :\phi(x) \implies \gamma(x)$ (by 2)
4. $\forall x \in E : \phi(x)$ (premise)
5. $\phi(x)$ (U.I, 4)
6. $\phi(x) \implies \gamma(x)$ (U.I, 3)
7. $\gamma(x)$ (M.P, 5, 6)
8. $\forall x \in E : \gamma(x)$ (U.G, 7)
9. $\forall x \in E : \phi(x)\implies \forall x \in E : \gamma(x)$ (conditional proof, 4 - 8)
10. $\forall x \in E (\phi(x) \implies \gamma(x)) \land (\forall x \in E : \phi(x))\implies \forall x \in E : \gamma(x))$
11. $\forall x \in E (\phi(x) \implies \gamma(x)) \implies [(\forall x \in E : \phi(x))\implies (\forall x \in E : \gamma(x))]$

Comment: That's great. One question: for going from step 10 to step 11 you are using the fact that $p⟹(q⟹r)\equiv (p\wedge q⟹r)$ right?

Comment: Yes, I can't recall of hand what it is called though

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Note that you can go a little bit further: $\forall x(\varphi(x)\implies\psi(x))$ implies $\forall x(\varphi(x))\implies\forall x(\psi(x))$. This is one direction of distributivity of $\forall$ over $\implies$.

As a cautionary note, let me point out that similar-looking principles may *not* hold, e.g.: it is not the case that $$[(\forall x\varphi(x))\implies (\forall x\psi(x))\quad \color{red}{\implies}\quad  \forall x(\varphi(x)\implies\psi(x))].$$ That is, distributivity doesn't go in both directions.

---

Note that distributivity *does* work both ways for $\forall$ over $\wedge$, but (again) works only one way for $\forall$ over $\vee$. Similar but dual results hold for distribution of $\exists$ over Boolean operations.

Comment: I did not know about distributing  ∀ over ⟹ in the direction you mention. This is really helpful.